# How to look for a certain value in first row and then copy all values in the same column

Tags: excel

In Excel I need to 'clean' a dataset from unnecessary columns. Thus it would be nice if I had a formula that takes the title from my 'result' worksheet's A1 and checks in the 'raw' worksheet's row 1 for it. Let's say it's in C1. Then I want to have the formula copy the entire column C ('raw' worksheet) to column A ('result' worksheet).

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: VBA would be better suited, but an INDEX/MATCH would work as a formula.  In A2 `=INDEX('RAW'!A:Z,Row(),MATCH($A$1,'RAW'!$1:$1,0))` then copy down.

Comment: @ScottCraner this looks good, but Excel doesn't accept this as a formula. I tried replacing the , with ; cause apparently it had issues with that but then it just says #NAME?

Comment: Do not copy and paste. Try retyping the formula directly with your `;`. Comments some times adds invisible characters.

Answer (score 0):

=INDEX(RAW!$A2:$AA2,1,MATCH(A$1,RAW!$1:$1,0)) is what ultimately worked, but only in Google Sheets. My Excel version did not accept MATCH for some reason -.- thanks for your help @ScottCraner